# Can't uninstall Windows Phone SDK 8 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

When I go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features and click to uninstall "Windows Phone SDK 8.0", the only option I get is "Change".

When I click "Change", it says "An error occurred while trying to uninstall Windows Phone SDK 8.0. It may have already been uninstalled. Would you like to remove Windows Phone SDK 8.0 from the Programs and Features list?"

When I click Yes it says I don't have permissions to remove it from the list.

I tried a Microsoft Fixit to fix uninstallation issues, but it said it could not succeed.

Comment: Do you have admin rights with this account?

Comment: Yes, my account is the administrator account. For what it's worth, using CCleaner to uninstall gives an error of "Error - could not find the file specified."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

reinistall SDK, reboot, install any updates, reboot, uninstall the SDK

I find this method works some of the time with stubborn applications

Comment: Accepting this answer because it got me to run the installer which had an option to uninstall. That method of uninstall works where the Programs and Features list was failing miserably.

Comment: Yes, ive seen that happen too.  For some reason the original installer works, while the installed application does not.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the command to force uninstall without doing any updates.

open Command Prompt and type the following

```
$ pathToExe/wpexpress_full.exe /uninstall /force
```

you can do this to VS12 as well.

```
$ pathToExe/vs_premium.exe /uninstall /force
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with VS2013 Update 2 or later, who comes across this question, there is no separate installation to uninstall. Per the [Windows Phone Dev Center](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk):

> The Windows Phone 8.1 development tools are included with Visual
>   Studio 2013 (Update 2 or later).

Comment: This question was about the **WP 8.0 SDK** not **WP 8.1 SDK** there is a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've if you open up the original Windows Phone SDK executable that you downloaded for installation, it should have a "Repair" and "Uninstall" button option.

Answer (score -1):

find the WPexpress_full.exe file same (C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{529db2e0-c334-4058-8ef0-9a214edbd1fa}\WPexpress_full.exe) right click -> Run as administrator -> unsintall -> yes (waiting..) -> reboot

Answer (score -1):

Update in 2016:
You can uninstall Windows Phone SDK from the "Change" menu of Microsoft Visual Studio.
Go in Control Panel -> Programs and Features and click "Change" for Microsoft Visual Studio